# FBJS JavaScript getElementById returning null?

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbjs, facebook-java-api

FBJS is driving my mental, I am having problems with selecting elements. I have the following on the content of my page:

```
 <button id="sendmessage" type="submit" style="border: 0; background: transparent">
        <img src="Button.png" alt="Submit" />
        <div id="output">Send Message</div><span id="overlay"></span>
  </button>
```

And as part of my FBJS  I have

```
var refSendMessage = document.getElementById('sendmessage');
var refOutput = document.getElementById('output');
```

However

```
refSendMessage.setDisabled(true);
```

Gets the error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'setDisabled' of null`

But

```
refOutput.setTextValue("Sending...");
```

Works fine!

Why is the type of refSendMessage null but refOutput is fine? The ID's are declared in the same place?

Need a JS wizard please :-)

Many thanks for your time,

---

Extra information, if I use `<span id="sendmessage"></span>`, no error occurs. Could this be a Facebook Bug?

Comment: It very well could be that Facebook isn't handling the button element properly and takes a crap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure you don't have anything else with id 'sendmessage' on the page.
2. Try to change `<button>` to an `<input type="button">` with id 'sendmessage' and see if document.getElementById('sendmessage') still returns null.  If not, perhaps Facebook has trouble with the `<button>` element?
3. Try looking at the rendered markup and make sure the Facebook-generated id specified inside document.getElementById() matches the Facebook-generated id of your button element.  If they don't match, then of course a null will be returned.